# Bash iterate through fields of a TSV file and divide it by the sum of the column

Tags: bash, awk

I have a tsv file with several columns, and I would like to iterate through each field, and divide it by the sum of that column:

Input:

```
A    1    2    1
B    1    0    3
```

Output:

```
A    0.5    1    0.25
B    0.5    0    0.75
```

I have the following to iterate through the fields, but I am not sure how I can find the sum of the column that the field is located in:

```
awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){$i=$i/SUM_OF_COLUMN}} 1' input.tsv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this 2-pass `awk`:

```bash
awk '
BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
NR == FNR {
   for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i)
      sum[i] += $i
   next
}
{
   for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i)
      $i = (sum[i] ? $i/sum[i] : 0)
}
1' file file

A       0.5     1       0.25
B       0.5     0       0.75
```

Comment: Let's say the file also has a header, how can I extend this script to print and skip the header? I tried using awk 'NR==1{print} NR>1{ ... } but it did not work as expected

Comment: You can insert `FNR == 1 {if (NR==1) print; next}` after `BEGIN` block

Comment: And for my understanding, why is the file passed twice to the awk command? In other words, what happens behind the scenes on these files?

Comment: We have to sum up the columns in first pass so that we can divide each column by the corresponding column sum in second pass.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code in a single pass of Input_file. Simply creating 2 arrays 1 for sum of columns with their indexes and other for values of fields along with their field numbers and in `END` block of this program traversing till value of `FNR`(all lines) and then printing values of arrays as per need (where when we are traversing through values then dividing their actual values with sum of that respective column).

```
awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} 
{
  arr[FNR,1]=$1
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    sum[i]+=$i
    arr[FNR,i]=$i
  }
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++){
    printf("%s\t",arr[i,1])
    for(j=2;j<=NF;j++){
      printf("%s%s",sum[j]?(arr[i,j]/sum[j]):"N/A",j==NF?ORS:OFS)
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file
```